# White Balance/ Filters

Tags: video-quality, lighting, filter

I have a silly question:
Do I have to the WB before or after choosing a Color filter?
If I do it after, then the camera will "see" white and the filter wouldn't make sense. If I do it before, why just not balance for the color temperature I want, say, 2900K if I want warm colors?
I am sure I don't understand something basic
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The ability to set custom white balances largely makes color filters unnecessary.  The only thing they really (potentially) offer is better dynamic range.  With a white balance adjustment, it alters the processing of what the sensors pick up, but if there is a really bright orange area for example, it could overload those sensors and thus detail would be lost if the rest of the image was darker.

Using a filter would reduce the amount of light of that color reaching the sensor and could potentially keep more detail.  This probably isn't going to happen in the vast majority of cases, but it is one physical difference between the two processes.  For the most part, color filters are a hold over from film days when there wasn't electronic white balancing.

Comment: does white balance adjustment impact capture speed? It does (or did) increase the required exposure time in DSLRs I have used.

Comment: @horation - would depend on how the camera is configured.  The image sensor itself still has the same light sensitivity.  The only difference is how it processes that.  If the reduction in sensitivity results in more information being needed to generate a standard exposure, then the length of exposure would have to be increased or the image would have to be gained up (increasing noise).  It is worth pointing out that the same thing would result from using an actual filter.

Comment: So, the progression would be:

Comment: Choose the light i want, for example: if I am going to use the window light, I would fill with reflector or a 5,600K light.

Comment: Then, i choose the filter if needed. and last WB, right?

Comment: @User17252 - if you want to use a filter, then yes, you would filter first, then apply white balancing electronically.  The only exception would be if you actually wanted to induce a tint, in which case you could white balance prior to applying the filter and then apply the filter to give the output a tint.

Comment: And one last question: normally if there is more than one light source, they should be the same temperature, right?, in witch cases yes and witch no?,thanks

Comment: Ideally, you want the same color light, but if you are going for an effect that appears like light is different you would use a different color.  For example, if you wanted light to look like it was coming in a sunny window, you'd use light with a slight tint.  Similarly, you could do this for giving a candle light look, or any other situation where you want the light to have a color to it.  You'd want one light to fill with the main color you are shooting (the key) with a fill light of the color you want to appear and mix the intensity to taste.